# How to stop wuauserv

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

Ever since I installed Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit, I am having a very high memory and CPU usage (Sometime above 90%). This keeps slowing my PC. So I looked at the task manager and found that svchost (netsvcs) is the culprit. Then I went to see the services run by svchost (netsvcs), where I identified wuauserv to be the ultimate culprit. Once I disabled it, everything became normal. I have also disabled windows update.
The problem is that wuauserv comes back alive after sometime and even though it does not start eating memory right after, it does it after sometime. So I want to know how to remove this wuauserv service.
I don't want windows updated. It usually slows down the computer and eats the internet speed. It even breaks the OS sometimes.

Comment: If what you're describing is actually happening constantly and never-ending, then it's a symptom of a different problem, not the problem itself. See the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/174452). "Ever since I installed Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit" was this a year ago, or 10 minutes ago? Have you ever actually let the updates run to completion? As-is this question is lacking too many specifics. CPU? RAM? Age? Disk check resutls? RAM Test results? You say you've disabled Windows Update, yet you ask how to disable Windows Update. :/

Comment: Your PC might be infected and some malware may hogging your CPU. Have you scanned your PC?

Comment: If you've been refusing to install updates, then it's very likely your system is infected with some bad thing or many bad things.

Comment: I have a windows 7 with a lot of hotfixes and updates pre installed. I have run eset and it detected no such thing as a malware. @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Sorry if I was vague. I will try not to be vague next time

Answer (score 2):

Do not do this. It's a critical Microsoft service and you cannot remove it without breaking a lot of things. There's really *no* excuse to not having an up-to-date operating system.

Comment: I am aware of it. However, It's very annoying when the OS eats away all the memory and I can't play a game without lagg.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you please tell me your Memory and CPU usage with all the windows updating?